# How to access the session variables from the add.php in grocery crud?

Tags: codeigniter, session, grocery-crud

I modified the add.php in grocery crud and add an iframe that shows the image crud. Now i need to add a conditional statement so that this iframe will show for some specific tables only. I set a flag in the controller for this. And my problem now is I dont know how will i access this session because

```
$this->session->userdata('isUploadVisible');
```

will generate an error

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Grocery_CRUD::$session

Filename: views/add.php

Line Number: 2
```

This add.php is the one that can be found in

```
  assets/grocery_crud/themes/datatables/views/add.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably use `$this` somewhere that it refers *this* to `Grocery_CRUD` Class. Try this:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->session->userdata('isUploadVisible');
```